# Permutations Problem Involving Men and Women in a Line Given 2 Conditions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many different ways can 8 people line up if...

There's two men that don't get along (can't be together)

AND

There's also two women that don't get along (can't be together either)?

I defined "M1" and "M2" as the two men who don't get along, and "W1" and "W2" as the two women who don't get along.

Then, I tried setting up a table with all the possible combinations:

[image]

But I'm sure I left out some of them because they seem to be too many. Is there a faster way or something I'm missing that could simplify this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: By "together" do you mean that they cannot be next to each other in the line?

Comment: Also, how many men and how many women are there? Are there $4$ men and $4$ women? Edit: I guess it doesn't matter how many are men and how many are women, if all $8$ people are distinguishable for the purposes of lining up - are they distinguishable?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee All the people are distinct, so it does not matter how many men and women there are, just that there are two pairs of _people_ that should not be together.

Comment: Assuming that's the case, your answer is perfect :)

Comment: Yes, the 8 people are distinguishable in the context of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the restrictions, the number of ways to order the people in a line is $8!$. For the restrictions, consider the two particular men and two particular women as one unit each, then we have

- number of ways with the men together is $2×7!$ (either one of them can be first)
- number of ways with the women together is $2×7!$
- number of ways with *both* groups together is $2×2×6!$ (two ways each of ordering the two people in each group)

This is the inclusion–exclusion principle, and what we get is that the number of admissible orderings is $8!-2×2×7!+2×2×6!=23040$.

Comment: I understood where the first two numbers (8! and 2x2x7!) came from; however, i'm confused as to how to determine the third (2x2x6!). If I try to join both groups and treat them as a single unit, I can only find 5 different ways of placing that 4-person unit. Also, why is this last term added and not subtracted?

Comment: @Sam202 You're not supposed to join both two-person groups together. They are separate from each other here, and this leaves six blocks to be placed (alongside the four isolated people). The last term is added because when we subtract $2×2×7!$ we subtract $2×2×6!$ arrangements too many, those where both the forbidden pairs are together, so we have to add the latter back; inclusion-exclusion generalises this to higher numbers of sets.